# App works on Iphone but doesnt work on Ipad

Tags: ios, objective-c

So I am new with IOS programming. I followed tutorials and decided to make a small universal application. So I created a button in Iphone storyboard and in code I made action that will play a sound. Then in storyboard I connected button to first responder action that plays a sound and it works fine. Then I created button in Ipad storyboard and did the same thing just as I did in Iphone, connected button to First Responder action, and when I open application in Ipad and click the button nothing happens

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need verify "Sent Events" section in IB.
[image: right action]

Comment: I did that,http://i.stack.imgur.com/kBaTm.png

Comment: Verify controller class
http://postimg.org/image/4yj3z0ohf/
and
http://postimg.org/image/vxnz7ukx9/
They are need will equal.

Answer (score 0):

This might be the issue of frame . 
Can you please do it programatically and check for the device i.e. iphone or iPad like following way and change the frame as per need on the view and your action code remain same for both. only frame set method parameter gets change.

```
UIButton  * myButton = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
    if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
    {
        [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(82.5, 240, 155, 35)];
        [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"sample_image", @"")] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"sample_image_HIGH", @"")] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    else
    {
        [myButton setFrame:CGRectMake(214, 505, 340, 77)];
        [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"sample_image_Ipad", @"")] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [myButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:NSLocalizedString(@"sample_image_HIGH_Ipad", @"")] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    }
    [myButton addTarget:self action:@selector(MyMethod)forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:myButton];
```

Comment: he said he works with storyboards, anyway your the image naming conventions are ugly; for _iPhone_ it should be `sample_image~iphone.png` for iPad it should be `sample_image~ipad.png`, and then you can refer the image as `sample_image.png` in your code, the iOS will load the device specific one – for those you don't need to check the device's interface idiom.